# Extra space being put in table cell

Tags: .net, asp.net, html

For some reason this code:

```
<td id="ddlHolidayCity" colspan="3">
                    <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Trx.TransactionHolidayCityCollection.Count; i++)
                        {%>
                            <%=i > 0 ? "," : ""%>
                            <%=DropDownData.HolidayDays().ToList().Find(item => item.Value == Model.Trx.TransactionHolidayCityCollection[i].HolidayCityID.Value.ToString()).Text%>
                        <%}
                    %>
                    </td>
```

Is displaying cities like this:

New York , London

-- see the extra space before the comma? Where is that coming from???

Comment: Is there an extra space after the New York ("New York ") in your data source?

Comment: That seems to look alright - perhaps I am missing something but where are the city names being outputted? Are you sure they don't contain any leading / trailing spaces prior to exiting the collection?

Comment: When you view source is it a newline? Can you just use your TransactionHolidayCityCollection and call Join() on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably coming from a newline or some other whitespace character just before escaping HTML to evaluate `i`. Since it's inside the `for` loop, it gets added to output. Try what happens if the spaces between angled brackets are removed:

```
<td id="ddlHolidayCity" colspan="3">
                    <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Trx.TransactionHolidayCityCollection.Count; i++)
                        {%><%=i > 0 ? "," : ""%>
                            <%=DropDownData.HolidayDays().ToList().Find(item => item.Value == Model.Trx.TransactionHolidayCityCollection[i].HolidayCityID.Value.ToString()).Text%>
                        <%}
                    %>
                    </td>
```

Comment: +1. Any white space in the HTML output (including line breaks) is rendered as a single space on the page.

Answer (score 0):

To test this change the code to one line.  Remove all spacing between your %> <%  I bet it will fix it.  See all the spacing below when I placed your code in a single line.
Coldfusion had a directive to tell the renderer how to interpret code page white space.

```
<td id="ddlHolidayCity" colspan="3">                     <% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Trx.TransactionHolidayCityCollection.Count; i++)                         {%>                             <%=i > 0 ? "," : ""%>                             <%=DropDownData.HolidayDays().ToList().Find(item => item.Value == Model.Trx.TransactionHolidayCityCollection[i].HolidayCityID.Value.ToString()).Text%>                         <%}                     %>                     </td>
```